# T-SQL Merge not warning about constraint violation

Tags: t-sql, insert, merge, foreign-keys, constraints

I have a trigger `INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE`
and I am using `MERGE` to merge update / insert the rows.

There is a FK Constraint on one of the columns, so if I try to insert something violating this constraint, it should show an error.

It shows an error if I try it directly with an `INSERT` statement. But it does not when the insert is being in the `WHEN NOT MATCHED` part of the MERGE statement.

Why ?

Comment: You need to come up with a script that reproduces the issue. I just threw a sample together based on your description, and I get "The MERGE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint ..." when it attempts to violate the FK constraint. (when the insert is attempted from the WHEN NOT MATCHED clause, while within an INSTEAD OF trigger)

Comment: OK then it means that it has to be my fault, because you have just proved that it works.